# AD license query

Tags: active-directory

A basic question about AD license, if on my company website, clients makes an account and would be authenticated through AD server, do i need to have the licenses for the clients coming via web.
and what all license would come into picture.

Answer (score 1):

If your users are authenticating to AD, then it is likely that you will need Authenticated SPLA licences for your server, however your best bet is to call MS Licencing and ask them. An even better bet is to call MS licencing more than once and ask different people there, as there answers often vary.

That said, id there any reason why your Web App needs to use AD to store it's user accounts? Using AD user accounts is generally only really done when you need other features of AD, like Exchange or SharePoint Access, if you just need to authenticate users then why not just store user accounts in your database. You'll save your self a lot of money because you will only need an unauthenticated Windows Licence.

Comment: If the internet based user accounts are saved in AD, then does it require License per user?

Comment: I believe you would need an authenticated processor SPLA licence for windows, but you would be best to check with MS

Comment: Actually you may not need SPLA but may be able to get away with an external connectpr license (http://forums.iis.net/t/1149662.aspx) - costs a crapload, but handles all user CAL in this case. That said, I stll think it is a brkoen approach to put users into AD for a web app only.

Comment: @TomTom good point, had forgot about the connector licence. Totally agree that putting users in AD, without needing any AD features is a bad idea.

Comment: what is the SPLA and when it is required? is it required in this case

Answer (score 0):

YOu need to have one CAL for every client then. UNLESS the client accounts are like web service hosting accounts and are basically for technical means. Depends a lot on the details here. What are "clients", what do they use the system for? (i.e. do they pay to use the system, like web hosting, or is the system only a means to an end, like a web shop like amazon where they pay for goods and not for system access).

Depending on the answer to that question, normal licensing may apply - or you may HAVE TO (!) use the SPLA (Service Provider License Agreement), which is more cheap and paid monthly.

If SPLA does not apply, an internet connector license may be used.

Comment: Little explanation: Ex. On some telecom site, if a user has made an account and has subscribed for e-bill etc, what is required in this case? One more thing, is it normal to have the web user authenticated through AD or ther is some other n secure approach?

Comment: Ok, that would mean system access for other use - SPLA may or may not apply. But actually NOONE makes AD for web appliations. Except you need AD for other means. So, in 99% of the cases the web application goes to the customer database. This would allow you to use SPLA and the Web Edition, insourcing license, extremely cheap - around USD 15 or so per processor. Contact Microsoft re SPLA.

Comment: What all v r looking for is, there is one newly added web application; whoever will access the new application (clients of the org.) a profile would be created n wud b saved in AD, in addition there wud b some more internal usrs (like customer service agents or Admins or Developers) who will access the application. Now, in my opinion for all internal users v need not to procure any license but for the external wo we need?
Another question:as u told, it is not advisable to have external user profiles on AD, Is it advisable to save the same on Database server n through LDAP it can access AD?

Comment: Well, you always have ADAM (Active Directory Application Mode) which you can use as LDAP database. But this would be slightly unusual - every website I know of basically has a SQL database holding not only the users, but also the other data.

Comment: ok, so the the user profile needs to be saved in Database and through LDAP get it authenticated to AD server, the flaw i see here is, my Database would be saved in SAN and is it really advisable to let the internet users reach to my SAN without any authentication, OR I can think of another scenario where I can put my AD server in DMZ and let the user profiles save on AD. whart  do you say now?
Other people expert advise also welcome...

Comment: Well, lets get real: 1: your users would reach the SAN anyway if the web app acccesses any information on the database there anyway. 2: if not, then move a copy of the database only for user authentication and only with this information into the dmz. Otherwise do not use AD - use an ADAM server.

Comment: If the users are first authenticated to AD, then where ever it may go does not makes a difference, but allowing them without authentication gives me shiver. What i am trying to do here is as follows. for an example. suppose I m a Telecom service provider n have recently made an application on my website so that my clients can make an online account n can avail some given benefits
Now, m trying to save the External users profile in AD server,as the users would be authenticated through AD server. why i am using AD- I am integrating my IMS (Identity management system) through it

Comment: @rajeev if your IMS system must use AD, then there will be no getting round creating accounts for users in AD, and your going to have to pay a licence fee for having authenticated users. Ring MS and get them to tell you what you need, we are not licencing experts and can only give you a best guess.

Comment: Actually I am ;) Sort of - I am SPLA provider and have all the documents at my disposal AND I actually use them monthly for about 2 years now to report my use ;)